# Lagging System or a possible bug in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, deep-learning

I am currently working on RnD in TensorFlow (CPU Version), but unable to decide on the basic requirement for my system for training on large datasets or may be I stumbled upon a possible bug in TensorFlow library.

The [Official TensorFlow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_guide), nowhere suggests any specific requirement for the system to be building and running TensorFlow programs on. From what I can understand, if that can be run over Windows, Linux, Mac along with Android, iOS and also over embedded systems like RaspberryPi, I suppose there should not be any such hardware requirement for the same.

However, while in the process of initial research, I tried running the TensorFlow Seq2Seq model (translating English to French https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/seq2seq), where the training and test datasets end up taking around 7-8 GB of diskspace initially and 20-22Gb on a whole. Once the translate.py python script is executed, it ends up choking the memory and pushing disk utilization to 98% and 100% respectively.

My current system runs Windows 8.1 64 bit OS, Core i5 5200U clocking at 2.2 GHz, 8GB RAM and around 70GB free space on HDD (specifically allotted for TensorFlow usage). But even after allowing my system to run over 7-8 hours (with no other application running) it got stuck multiple times and usually after the memory utilization peeks to around 100% after tokenizing the datasets.

Though I am not sure, but I suppose the TensorFlow learning graph is being created inside the RAM and once it expands to around all the memory space, the program ends up in un-ending loop waiting for memory to get cleared and then increase the learning graph.

So the whole drills down to 3 questions:

1. Does TensorFlow uses RAM for building and saving Learning Graph? If so, is it possible to get choked in a similar fashion?
2. From a business perspective, is there a minimum hardware requirement for training such a system?
3. If it is not the system requirement, can this be a possible bug in TensorFlow library which pushes it into an unending loop waiting for memory to get cleared?

**Update**

After running the python script for over 30 hours continuously, the process seems to have stuck at the same place for past 14 hours while "Reading development and training data". Refer image below for further investigation:

[image]

Comment: This is not a bug, it just seems your computer has too little RAM to do Deep Learning on a 20GB dataset. And not even considering GPUs.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro, can you please elaborate a little on the learning graph creation process? Is that created in the RAM or somewhere else? And is there a minimum requirement for a system to run such a process?

Comment: Yes in RAM, you shouldn't think of minimum requirements, as that completely depends on the task and your patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as I was about to shut down the program, the same started responding again and I waited for another 15-20 minutes and finally I got the answer from the OS itself. It was indeed low RAM that was causing the problem. Attaching the screen grab of the Windows Alert of system running low on memory for reference, incase anyone gets caught in same situation.

[image]

**UPDATE**

I tried taking a VM instance on Google Cloud Platform. This machine had 2 x Intel Xeon (R) each running at 2.23 GHZ, with 13GB RAM and 50GB storage. But the result was same in this situation also even though the application was utilising more than 10.5 GB RAM. Seems like this tutorial script needs a very intense system probably a Super Computer with atleast 32 GB RAM to run and execute completely. I might look to write/arrange my own dataset now. However, this must be taken as future enhancement to use Persistent Storage (HDD/SSD) to create the Graph instead of RAM so as to avoid chocking of Memory.